# Check to see if variable exists..inline sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

SQL Server 2016 .Net 4.5.2 C#

I say this with respect, I am using the Northwind database to show what I'm trying to achieve. Please, no comments about the Northwind database. This is just an example of what i will be doing.

I am using ADO.Net to execute inline sql. My dilemma is i will have optional parameters that might be passed to the sql query. Here's the C#:

```
var city = "";
var state = "tx";
var sqlQuery = "
       if exists @City
       begin
       select * from Customers where city = @City and state=@State;
       end
       else
       begin
        select * from Customers where state=@State;
       end
    ";

var conn =  new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(city))
{
    SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@City";
    param.Value         = city;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
}   

if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(state))
{
    SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@State";
    param.Value         = state;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
}

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

As you can see, the variable city is blank so the parameter @City will not be passed to the sql query, but the variable state is not blank so @State parameter will be passed to the query. Keep in mind, @City will not be blank all the time. I put a check in the sql to see if @City exists, but that does not work. How do I check in the sql query if @City, @State or any other parameters that might be passed in exist? If i can figure that part out, I can handle what needs to be done in the sql. Thanks for any and all help.

P.S. I cannot use stored procedures.

Comment: Why can't you use a stored procedure? That is a strange restriction.

Comment: I agree. My job has put handcuffs on me. We use all inline sql. I'm not sure this is possible what they want

Comment: It is absolutely possible. See my answer. I feel bad for the place you work with such absurd restrictions. I have heard of this kind of thing before and it always boils down to some person who is misinformed and in a position to make such sweeping mandates. The worst part is that same person is also usually dead set in their misguided beliefs and refuses to listen to reason. You either have to deal with that kind of nonsense or clean up your resume.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from
    Customers
where
    state=@State
    AND (city = @City
       OR ISNULL(@City,'') = '')
```

I would recommend the above you can do it in 1 select statement without having to use IF control methods.  It will test city, but it will also say if @City is blank then return it anyway because only 1 of those conditions can be true at a time you will never end up getting results you don't want.  To use the control method you could do something like the following,

```
IF ISNULL(@City,'') <> ''
BEGIN
    select * from Customers where city = @City and state=@State;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select * from Customers where state=@State;
END
```

But again the first example would be more standard and is less code so I would recommend that.

Edit:
You have to pass the parameter every time.  Otherwise you would actually change the SQL statement in your C# code not in your SQL code.

Next you will actually pass an empty string NOT a NULL value looking at your assignment of `var city = "";` so you can switch to test for that.

The problem with NOT passing the parameter at all is your SQL statement will use a variable that you have not declared if you don't add the parameter value.  So the standard way is to Always Pass the variable and to use a SQL statement like the first one above.  IF you really want to do it in a different way to not even pass at all then you will need to use the c# control flow to build your SQL string differently.

Standard Way:

```
var city = "";
var state = "tx";
var sqlQuery = "
    select *
    from
        Customers
    where
        state=@State
        AND (city = @City
            OR ISNULL(@City,'') = '')
";

var conn =  new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@City";
param.Value         = city;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@State";
param.Value         = state;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Way of doing it without passing parameter is to dynamically build your SQL statement through the c# control flow:

```
var city = "";
var state = "tx";
var sqlQuery = "
    select *
    from
        Customers
    where
        state=@State
";

if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(city))
{
    sqlQuery += "
            AND city=@City";
}

var conn =  new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(city))
{
    SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@City";
    param.Value         = city;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
}

SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@State";
param.Value         = state;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

To expand a little more on why you got `must declare scalar variable @city` when you didn't pass the paramter is because the parameter definition in c# is what defines the variable in SQL.  So:

```
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@City";
param.Value         = city;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Essentially does this in SQL:

```
DECLARE @City VARCHAR(50)
SET @City = value of city var.
```

So if you omit this step as you are doing by using a if control flow on city var you omit the variable definition and SQL will fail.  So while the value of a parameter may be optional the parameter itself is NOT option if it is referenced in your SQL statement.

Also Note you are using implicit data types in parameter definitions you really should explicitly define the data type!

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@City".

Comment: @BoundForGlory you should always pass the variable weather it Null or Not.  you do have another issue though that you are passing an empty string not a null so I updated to reflect how to check for that.

Comment: The requirement i have is do not pass the parameter if the variable is null. Thats why I wrote the code the way I did. I even tried a try catch, but that failed.

Comment: why is that a requirement?  Standard coding would be you would pass the parameter but it would be NULL!  If you do not you will have to use control flow in C# to make the statements completely different before executing one of them.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this is coming from where i work. Thats why i cant use stored procedures. This isn't me trying to do something on my own. I would use a sproc in a heartbeat if i could

Comment: In my answer and my suggestion there are no stored procedures

Comment: your answer doesnt work.  
Must declare the scalar variable "@City"

Comment: My answer does work if you PASS THE PARAMETER every time which is what my comments say.  I shouldn't be helping you anymore at this point seeing you clearly need to go back to learning what a stored procedure is what a definition of a parameter is and a few other things but because I was almost done I will show you the proper and standard code include the changes to the C#

Comment: I'm done with this conversation. I CLEARLY stated and shown in code what my job is asking me to do and you keep suggesting what i'm not allowed to do at work. I know how to pass a null into a parameter. I don't need stack for that. Good day

Comment: @BoundForGlory then call me DENSE because I don't CLEARLY see that you are getting the idea of optional parameters.  I did however answer for others that may stumble on the question.  and I expanded as to why you are having a problem because the values of a parameter are optional but a parameter is NOT optional if it is defined in your SQL statement.  Another suggestion is to explicitly define your data types in your parameter definition strings aren't usually an issue unless you have special encoding but dates can be misinterpreted datatypes when using implicit definition.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing pass through sql it is challenging to use optional parameters. And it really doesn't help make your code any better. Option parameters would be useful in a stored procedure but in a pass through query it is far more effort than it is worth. The best way to deal with this is to always pass the parameters. But you can pass a DBNull and handle that in your query.

I would also strongly suggest you start wrapping your iDisposable objects in a USING statement. Especially things like connections and commands. You do NOT want to hose your connection pool because you miss a Dispose call by accident.

Here is one way you can manage this type of thing pretty cleanly.

```
var sqlQuery = "select *
from Customers
where 
(
    state = @State
    OR
    @state is null
)
AND
(
    city = @City
    OR
    @City is null
)";

using (SqlConnection conn =  new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
    {
        SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@City";
        if (string.IsNullorEmpty(city))
        {
            param.value = DBNull.Vale;
        }
        else
        {
            param.Value = city;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@State";
        if(string.IsNullorEmpty(state))
        {
            param.value = DBNull.Vale;
        }
        else
        {
            param.Value = state;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, and trust me i would do this if i owned the company i work for. This is a work requirement and i'm not sure if it's possible what they want me to do.

Comment: It is a work requirement that you can't pass the parameters to your pass through query each time? That just makes no sense at all. I feel your pain and sense your frustration as some stupid mandate from a person in power with little to no understanding of how this works. The only I can see making your parameters optional is to create a branch in c# for every possible combination and only include the parameters relevant to that path. Talk about a nightmare!!!